# SVN post-commit updating to incorrect version

Tags: svn

We have an odd issue with SVN and its post-commit hook.

We have a number of sites, and this issue only affects one (at least that I've found). There's a post-commit hook with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
WC=/srv/www/sites/sitename

date | tee -a $REPOS/hooks/log.txt
cd $WC && svn update 2>&1 >> $REPOS/hooks/log.txt
echo | tee -a $REPOS/hooks/log.txt
```

The hook runs when I commit; the directory exists; and the user it's run as has the correct permissions to access the directory (I've tweaked the code for the hook to echo both to the log file to check.)

When I su to the user, and change to the directory, I can run `svn update` - it will update with the latest revision. When I do it through the hook, it won't.

I've done some poking, and discovered that when the hook is run, `svn update` is triggered; but it's not doing anything with the new revision that's just been committed. I removed a file from the target directory, and commited a change - the file was restored, but from an earlier revision - the last revision I'd updated manually, in fact.

There's clearly something odd going on, but I can't figure out what. The configuration of the repository looks OK, but I don't know enough about SVN to narrow it down any further. I'd appreciate any hints anyone might have as to where to look next.

**Edit**

`svn info` gives me:

```
URL: file:///srv/svn/repos/sitename/trunk
Repository Root: file:///srv/svn/repos/sitename
Repository UUID: 8f30e7d8-358c-4aa0-ba90-4bb80c6b434e
Revision: 132
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: authorname
Last Changed Rev: 132
Last Changed Date: 2013-06-17 09:47:46 -0400 (Mon, 17 Jun 2013)
```

The output from the logfile isn't helpful; when I just commit files, I'm seeing:

```
Mon Jun 17 10:05:08 EDT 2013
```

Which was the time the commit was last made. `svn update` is not outputting anything into the log file.

I've just created a new revision - I've added a new file to my local copy of the repository, and deleted `README` from the target directory. That gives me the following in the log file:

```
Mon Jun 17 10:11:44 EDT 2013
Restored 'README'
```

The revision I've just commited was 134. There's no sign of the new file , and `svn info` tells me that the Last Changed Rec is still 132.

**Edit, again**

I've added some debug code to the hook, as requested:

```
echo $@ >> /tmp/tempfile;
env | tee -a /tmp/tempfile;
```

This gives:

```
/srv/svn/repos/sitename 150
OLDPWD=/
PWD=/srv/www/sites/sitename
```

150 is the revision I've just added.

**Edit, again**

As requested. The first one is from when I made a change and committed it (nothing was updated); the second is after I deleted a file, and committed again (the file was restored, but from an earlier version)

```
/srv/svn/repos/sitename 153
OLDPWD=/
PWD=/srv/www/sites/sitename

/srv/svn/repos/sitename 154
OLDPWD=/
PWD=/srv/www/sites/sitename
```

**Edit, again, again**

I've created a new working directory, while logged in as www-data. I did the initial checkout as the same user; and then committed. And `svn update` didn't do anything.

I'm as sure as I can be that this isn't an obvious file permission error. The hook is definitely running the `svn update` command, because when I delete a file from the working directory and run a commit, it's restoring the file I deleted.

It's as though svn isn't seeing the new version. The command I'm currently using in the hook is:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
WC=/srv/www/sites/sitename
/usr/bin/svn update -r $REV "$WC" 2>&1
```

`$1` is the right repository name. `$2` is the correct, latest, version number. `$WC` is the correct directory.

- When I commit a file, the hook is run, but doesn't update (even with the -r flag set).
- When I run `svn commit` as the right user, in the right directory, it updates properly
- When I delete a file from the working directory, and commit, that file is restored, but from the most recent revision run manually.

And in the interest of completness, I've also tried using older versions of the revision number. When I did `/usr/bin/svn update -r 10 "$WC" 2>&1` [that's about 140 revisions ago], it made no changes - nothing deleted, nothing added.

**Update the fifth**

Adding the `svn update` into cron did exactly the same as when it was started off by the post-commit hook; it would update to the last version I'd run `svn update` for, but newer revisions would be omitted. If there were no differences between the working directory and that last version, it would do nothing. And yes, cron was being run. I tried this both as the correct user, and as root, being somewhat frustated at that point.

Additionally, I've just recreated the repo and the working directory. I added the content from my local working directory to the new repo, and it's behaving exactly the same way. Even though the setup is identical to a different development site which I set up this morning.

So I'm giving up at this point. The hassle involved in trying to fix this properly far outweighs the inconvenience of having to update it manually occasionally. Thank you all for reading this, and for your suggestions.

Comment: is there anything interesting in your `log.txt`? maybe adding the output of `svn info` to the logfile helps.

Comment: @krissi - thanks for the response. I've added some of the output from `log.txt` to the question, for what it's worth, as well as `svn info`.

Comment: Perhaps you are having an issue with the environment or permissions of the user who runs the script?  Try adding env >> logfile or something similar to check how the executing user's environment looks.

Comment: Try to add `-r` to your update command: `cd "$WC" && /usr/bin/svn update -r "$REV" 2>&1 >> "$REPOS/hooks/log.txt"`. I use it in my scripts. I also replaced the command with the absolute path.

Comment: @krissi - the `-r` didn't help, I'm afraid - there was nothing output. I know it's not an issue with the path, because `svn update` is running - it restored the file I'd deleted. It's just not picking up the new version.

Comment: You say this same script is running successfully on other servers?  Are the permissions/ownership for $WC set exactly the same on all of them?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - the same script is running for other repos on the same server. I can't see any differences between permissions or ownerships between this script and one of the working ones.

Comment: Are you certain that $2 is evaluating to the youngest revision/most recent commit?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - I've just used `su -` to log in as the user the post-commit runs as, and run the `svn update` in the right directory with no problems. I can't see anything majorly different between the environment set when I'm logged in as the user, and when the script is running via the hook.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - now that is an excellent thought. I'll have a check and see.

Comment: Tarnation. Yes, $2 is indeed showing up as the newest revision.

Comment: What if you change the code to `cd "$WC" && svn update "$WC" 2>&1 >> $REPOS/hooks/log.txt`

Comment: Are you running this in Apache?  What user does apache run as (nobody,www,httpd) ?  Who are the owner and group owner for the working copy?  What are the permissions on the working copy?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - it's running in apache. It's running as www-data, and the working copy is owned by nvadmin. The local copy has group write permissions. It's not a problem with svn not being able to write to the right directory, because it does so properly when it's restoring a file. (I've also just chowned everything in that directory to www-data and tried it again - it's still not updating with the new revision)

Comment: What I'm currently wondering is, how does `svn update` figure out what version it needs to update to? There doesn't seem to be anything in the target directory to say what version it's on, so is there a config file in the repo somewhere that tracks the current version, that maybe isn't being updated?

Comment: Does `svnlook youngest $REPO` report the latest revision for each repo?  svn update can take a revision as an argument to the -r switch, why don't you try changing your script to `svn update -r $2 "$WC"` since you verified that $2 is properly evaluating to the youngest revision.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - *sob*. `svnlook youngest $REPO` shows me 146, which is my latest test version. The post-cmmit hook now includes `svn update -r $REV "$WC"`, which produced no output at all (and didn't update anything). I've checked that $REV and $WC are both being set properly, by echoing out that line. And cutting and pasting the line from the log file, while logged in as www-data using `su -`, updates it. I'm getting to the point where I'm thinking of scrapping the repo and starting again with one copied from a known-working project.

Comment: Do me a favor and add this line to the script
` echo $@ >> /tmp/tempfile;
echo env >> /tmp/tempfile `

and show me the contents of /tmp/tempfile

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - I've added the output to the question.

Comment: Can you specify the full path to svn update in your script and try it again?

Comment: Can you make a copy of the entire working copy directory, naming it sitename.copy , then do `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/www/sites/sitename ` First, to be sure the script is running as the www-data user, try adding whoami >> /tmp/tempfile to the script to be sure it is running as that user.  Also make sure that the hook/script itself is owned by that user.

Comment: Are you using https or only http?

Comment: I think we're just using http.

Comment: ok. The hook is owned by www-data:www-data; that is the username with which it's running. The site was already chowned to www-data:www-data - I think I did that earlier. It's (*sigh*) still not behaving. 
One thing - I did a manual svn update earlier, in the wrong directory, and got an error (and rightly so); do you know where the configuration is set up so that when I run `svn update` in a given directory, it knows which repo to pull it from?

Comment: I believe there is a hidden .svn directory in the working copy which keeps all of that metadata.  Depending on client version it can be in each subdirectory in the WC (pre 1.7X client) or at the root of the WC (1.7X) Most likely it would be in the .svn folder in a file called Entries I believe.

Comment: You tried it with the full path for svn update? `/usr/bin/svn update`

Comment: It is indeed using the full path. I'm currently checking out everything into a new working directory; I'll swap the two over and see if that works.

Comment: So, I looked into this a little and it seems doing updates via post commit hook is a little more complex than it seems.  See Justin's answer here https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-51797.html Are you certain the other servers are setup exactly the same and that they are working properly with this script being used to do an svn update?

Comment: Well, that didn't help either - I did a full checkout of the repo into a brand new directory; and changed the post-commit to use the new directory, and still nothing. Bah!

Comment: Basically, I recommend that you actually create a directory that is owned by www-data user, su to www-data and then mkdir, then do an svn checkout while still being the www-data user into that dirctory that the www-data user created.  See if that gets updated properly by the script.

Comment: We have a couple of hundred development sites on the same server, and as far as I can tell, this is the only one that is failing. I've used `diff` to compare this post-commit file with one I know is working, and the only difference that found was the directory name. I checked the file permissions as well as I could, but they all seemed fine, too.

Comment: Alternately, you can try using the --username switch to svn update and hardcoding your svn credentials into the script (if you are comfortable with that)

Comment: Please fold the relevant information from these comments into questions and/or answers...

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a cron job run every few minutes to update the working copy.  It will circumvent the trouble you are having doing this as a post commit hook and it will save the developers the trouble of having to wait for an svn update to complete every time they commit.

Comment: I give up. I've just added a new cronjob, with the single line `/usr/bin/svn update /srv/www/sites/sitename`. It doesn't do anything - it's run, but there's no output. When I cut and paste the same line from crontab to a prompt, it works. I've tried this as the correct user, and as root. I think I might just make the developers request updates at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this. I do appreciate it, even if we get to the bottom of it.

Comment: You sure cron service is running?  I would probably put it under /etc/cron.hourly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and the following worked for me.

1. I added logging to stderr of `svn up` command inside post-commit hook:

```
    svn up >> $REV.log 2>>$REV-error.log
```

2. Discovered the following error:

```
    svn: E000022: Error converting entry in directory '<...>' to UTF-8
    svn: E000022: Can't convert string from native encoding to 'UTF-8':
    svn: E000022: Listok No2.tex
```

3. Figured out that there should be some locale-related problem as locales can be different in my default profile and empty profile which is used in svn up (probably, as well as crontab).
4. Added necessary fixes to post-commit hook.

```
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    export LANG
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8 svn up >> $REV.log 2>>$REV-error.log
```

Now it works.

Not sure it will help OP (after 6 years) and the problem can be different, but I believe that locale-related problems are usual suspect when things are different after running from command line and from cron or other scripts with empty environments.